# Problema con espaciado en php en manejo de archivos

Tags: php

Explico el programa

1. Crea un archivo .txt a base de un arreglo.
2. Si se presiona el botón "leer" se lee un archivo usando la función leer_archivo.
3. Si se presiona el botón "ordenar" se busca un archivo de texto, en este caso el que fue creado antes y se lo convierte a un arreglo para ser pasado por la función *quicksort* que lo ordenará y luego, nuevamente, lo guardará a un archivo nuevo con las lineas en orden.

Problema:

Cuando se crea el segundo archivo, ordena bien los elementos **pero deja una linea de espacio entre ellos**, cosa que me gustaría cambiar.

Ejemplo:

Resultado deseado:

```
XXXXX 
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

Resultado Obtenido

```
XXXXX

XXXXX

XXXXX
```

Dejo el código

```
<?php 

$n_archivo = 'nuevo_archivo.txt';
//array para crear un nuevo archivo
$ordenar = array('carro','auto','01','0001','zorro','alto','piensa','zorro');
//creando nuevo archivo
nuevo_archivo($ordenar,'nuevo_archivo.txt');

if (isset($_POST['leer']))//si fue presionado leer ...
{
    leer_archivo($n_archivo,FALSE);
}
elseif (isset($_POST['ordenar']))//si fue presionado ordenar ...
{

    nuevo_archivo(quicksort(leer_archivo($n_archivo,TRUE)),'ordenado.txt');
    leer_archivo('ordenado.txt',FALSE);

}

echo <<<_END
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Examen quicksort Leonel Becerra</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="quicksort_examen.php">
            Leer Archivo    <input type="submit" name="leer" value="leer">
            Ordenar archivo <input type="submit" name="ordenar" value="ordenar">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>

_END;

//lee un archivo, si $array es falso solo lo imprime, si es verdadero crea un array de elementos con cada linea del archivo
function leer_archivo($nombre,$array)
{
    $fh = fopen("$nombre",'r')or die ($php_errormsg);

    if(!$array)
    {

        while(!feof($fh))
        {
            echo fgets($fh)."<br/>";
        }

        fclose($fh) or die ($php_errormsg);
    }
    else
    {
        $arreglo;
        $i = 0;
        while(!feof($fh))
        {                       
            $arreglo[$i] = fgets($fh);
            $i++;
        }

        fclose($fh) or die ($php_errormsg);

        return $arreglo;

    }

}

//ordenamiento por quicksort
function quicksort($array)
{
    $tamaño = count($array); //encontrando el tamaño del arreglo

    if($tamaño <= 1 ) //caso base
    {
        return($array);
    }
    else
    {
        $pivot = $array[0]; //asignando pivot

        $menor = array(); //array para menores que pivot
        $mayor = array(); //array para mayores que pivot

        for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) //poniendo cada elemento en su lugar comparandolos con el pivot
        {
            if($array[$i] < $pivot)
            {
                $menor[] = $array[$i];
            }
            else
            {
                $mayor[] = $array[$i];
            }
        }

        return array_merge(quicksort($menor), array($pivot), quicksort($mayor)); /*une arreglos $menor con $pivot con $mayor*/
    }
}

//crea un nuevo archivo tomando como parametro un arreglo
function nuevo_archivo($array,$nombre)
{
    $fh = fopen("$nombre", 'w') or die ($php_errormsg);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
        $temp = $array[$i];
        $temp = sanitizar_variable($temp);
        $temp = $temp."\r\n";
        fwrite($fh,$temp) or die ($php_errormsg);
    }

    fclose($fh);

}

//usada para quitar slashes, codigo html y tags html
function sanitizar_variable($var)
{
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);

    return $var;
}

//Imprime el arreglo, usado para debugging
function imprimir_arreglo($array)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
        echo "$array[$i]";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que las lineas **YA** tienen el salto de linea, al agregarle otro con  `."\r\n"` se duplican y ves los saltos dobles. Esto pasa por que `fgets` lee la linea completa, incluido el `\r\n\` del final.

Lo mejor seria eliminar el salto de linea cuando lees el archivo. Modificando este pedazo de la función `leer_archivo` y utilizando [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php).

```
$arreglo[$i] = trim(fgets($fh));
```

Comment: Perfecto !, había leído sobre que ya añadía un salto de linea pero después de intentar varios métodos me había rendido, este fue el indicado.